# Does B4's Name Have A Significant Meaning?

Tags: star-trek

Brent Spiner said he was originally named B9, but changed it to B4 because Lost in Space had a robot named B9. So to ask, does B4 have a significant meaning?

Comment: *"because he was the fourth made."* Didn't you just answer your question?

Comment: B4 was the third made

Comment: Perhaps the "B" stands for "Brent".  B-4 is the fourth member of the Soong family — after Data, Lore, and Noonien, in their various ages and appearances — to be played by Brent Spiner.

Answer (score 15):

Per the Memory Alpha article on [B-4](https://memory-alpha.fandom.com/wiki/B-4):

> According to the original Star Trek Nemesis script, the android B-4 ("before") was named "B-9" ("benign"). Also according to the script, the android was taken from its homeworld by the Pakleds and traded to the Bolians. He ultimately encountered some Cardassians, who tossed him into a garbage chute and out into space, where he was found by Talosians. It was also revealed that Shinzon had learned of the prototype android through a Cardassian historian. None of this, however, made it to the final version of the script. The novelization names him as "Be-Fore".

It seems "B-9" was originally chosen as a play on words for "benign", but was changed out for "B-4" to be a play on the word "before". This also fits his backstory as a less advanced android who came before his brothers Lore and Data. The article on [Soong-type androids](https://memory-alpha.fandom.com/wiki/Soong-type_android) does make mention of three prototypes that predated Lore/Data (according to a quote from the TNG episode "[Inheritance](https://memory-alpha.fandom.com/wiki/Inheritance_(episode))"), which means B-4 was among these (although we don't know the order).

But this doesn't address the out-of-universe reason for why it was changed. It's possible that is was for the one you mentioned (B9 already being from *Lost in Space*), but I've not found any references to it.

Comment: I was just going to post this! Beaten by seconds. ;-)

Comment: @BCdotWEB I knew I had to be quick :P But what is listed on the wiki only gives what it was and what it became, not the reason why. I've yet to find anything that gives a reason, but if someone could, that would still be a more complete answer than what I have.

Comment: Was B4 actually created by Noonien Soong?

Comment: @DataTNGlover Yes, hence why he looks like Noonien as well.

Comment: "In universe" means what happens inside the fiction of the universe. "Out of universe" means things that happen in real life, in out universe. Are you saying that the *writers* were doing a play on words, or, was *Dr. Noonian Soong* doing the play on words?

Comment: @Shane "*I told him Brent Spiner said he was originally named B9, but changed it to B4 because Lost in Space had a robot named B9.*" Referring to OP's claim that there was an out-of-universe need to change from B-9 to B-4. As far as the play on words, both actually. The writers intended it as such, and Picard notes Soong's penchant for whimsical names in *Star Trek: Nemesis* after encountering B-4.